# alternative built-in function to use ? or any code snippets you got there?

Tags: php

money_format doesn't work on windows, at least from what I read in the manual..but I was given this app, wherein it uses money_format(), i guess it doesn't have a problem on a production server because probably it's using linux. but I can't develop it in my local coz it throws a fatal error..any alternative built-in function for this? or any code snippets you might wanna share to me?

```
<?php echo money_format('%n', $_SESSION["shoppingbag"]->getSubTotal()); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest you can get is [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

If you need it just to be able to develop on windows you can simply do:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('money_format') {
  include('Dani\'s answer.php');
} 
echo money_format('%n', $_SESSION["shoppingbag"]->getSubTotal()); ?>
```

Comment: yeah, I googled, but still waiting for other devs opinions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060))

```
<?php 
/* 
That it is an implementation of the function money_format for the 
platforms that do not it bear.  

The function accepts to same string of format accepts for the 
original function of the PHP.  

(Sorry. my writing in English is very bad)  

The function is tested using PHP 5.1.4 in Windows XP 
and Apache WebServer. 
*/ 
function money_format($format, $number) 
{ 
    $regex  = '/%((?:[\^!\-]|\+|\(|\=.)*)([0-9]+)?'. 
              '(?:#([0-9]+))?(?:\.([0-9]+))?([in%])/'; 
    if (setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0) == 'C') { 
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, ''); 
    } 
    $locale = localeconv(); 
    preg_match_all($regex, $format, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
    foreach ($matches as $fmatch) { 
        $value = floatval($number); 
        $flags = array( 
            'fillchar'  => preg_match('/\=(.)/', $fmatch[1], $match) ? 
                           $match[1] : ' ', 
            'nogroup'   => preg_match('/\^/', $fmatch[1]) > 0, 
            'usesignal' => preg_match('/\+|\(/', $fmatch[1], $match) ? 
                           $match[0] : '+', 
            'nosimbol'  => preg_match('/\!/', $fmatch[1]) > 0, 
            'isleft'    => preg_match('/\-/', $fmatch[1]) > 0 
        ); 
        $width      = trim($fmatch[2]) ? (int)$fmatch[2] : 0; 
        $left       = trim($fmatch[3]) ? (int)$fmatch[3] : 0; 
        $right      = trim($fmatch[4]) ? (int)$fmatch[4] : $locale['int_frac_digits']; 
        $conversion = $fmatch[5]; 

        $positive = true; 
        if ($value < 0) { 
            $positive = false; 
            $value  *= -1; 
        } 
        $letter = $positive ? 'p' : 'n'; 

        $prefix = $suffix = $cprefix = $csuffix = $signal = ''; 

        $signal = $positive ? $locale['positive_sign'] : $locale['negative_sign']; 
        switch (true) { 
            case $locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 1 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+': 
                $prefix = $signal; 
                break; 
            case $locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 2 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+': 
                $suffix = $signal; 
                break; 
            case $locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 3 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+': 
                $cprefix = $signal; 
                break; 
            case $locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 4 && $flags['usesignal'] == '+': 
                $csuffix = $signal; 
                break; 
            case $flags['usesignal'] == '(': 
            case $locale["{$letter}_sign_posn"] == 0: 
                $prefix = '('; 
                $suffix = ')'; 
                break; 
        } 
        if (!$flags['nosimbol']) { 
            $currency = $cprefix . 
                        ($conversion == 'i' ? $locale['int_curr_symbol'] : $locale['currency_symbol']) . 
                        $csuffix; 
        } else { 
            $currency = ''; 
        } 
        $space  = $locale["{$letter}_sep_by_space"] ? ' ' : ''; 

        $value = number_format($value, $right, $locale['mon_decimal_point'], 
                 $flags['nogroup'] ? '' : $locale['mon_thousands_sep']); 
        $value = @explode($locale['mon_decimal_point'], $value); 

        $n = strlen($prefix) + strlen($currency) + strlen($value[0]); 
        if ($left > 0 && $left > $n) { 
            $value[0] = str_repeat($flags['fillchar'], $left - $n) . $value[0]; 
        } 
        $value = implode($locale['mon_decimal_point'], $value); 
        if ($locale["{$letter}_cs_precedes"]) { 
            $value = $prefix . $currency . $space . $value . $suffix; 
        } else { 
            $value = $prefix . $value . $space . $currency . $suffix; 
        } 
        if ($width > 0) { 
            $value = str_pad($value, $width, $flags['fillchar'], $flags['isleft'] ? 
                     STR_PAD_RIGHT : STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        } 

        $format = str_replace($fmatch[0], $value, $format); 
    } 
    return $format; 
} 

?>
```